# Google maps API, callback is a method of object

Tags: javascript, google-maps, callback, cross-domain

I've ripped out every single line of code here with the exception of this:

```
show = foo.show = function () {
    alert("test");
};
```

Now, it works if I run the maps API in this way:

```
foo.display = function() {
    this.elem = document.getElementById('fooBox');

    var script  = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src  = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=show";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
};
```

But when I try to call it via the `callback=foo.show` it fails:

```
foo.display = function() {
    this.elem = document.getElementById('fooBox');

    var script  = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src  = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=foo.show";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
};
```

The only error I can get form WebKit inspector is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'show' of undefined`.

I'm new to the google maps API, but I would have thought methods don't matter? I'm sure I've seen it done somewhere. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is `foo` declared as a `var`? If so, it's not accessible to the global scope.  Add a declaration like:

```
foo = {};

foo.show = function () {
   ...
};

...
```

to your code and it's likely to correct the issue. The response from WebKit indicates that the variable `foo` is not in scope at the time `show()` is invoked.